# Spreadsheet - Im trying to find the sum of the top n numbers in two columns

Tags: excel, google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

-UPDATED- Answered, thanks for all who helped.

Consider the following Google spreadsheet:

```
   A      B     C     D     E
1       John | Bob | Sue | Tony
2  h1     2  |  1  |  3  |  2
3  h2     3  |  3  |  4  |  2
4  h3     1  |  2  |  1  |  3
5  h4     2  |  2  |  3  |  1
6  h5     2  |  1  |  1  |  3
7  h6     1  |  2  |  2  |  1
8  h7     1  |  2  |  1  |  3

Team  |  Player1  |  Player 2  |  Score
  1   |   John    |    Sue     |    ?
  2   |   Bob     |    Tony    |    ?
```

Each team is made of two partners, e.g. John and Sue. Each row contains a match: the team's score is the best of each member's. The team total score of the game is the sum of the match scores.

In the example:

- Team 1 : John & Sue. Match scores: (3,4,1,3,2,2,1). Total score = 16.
- Team 2 : Bob & Tony. Match scores: (2,3,3,2,3,2,3). Total score = 18.

Another example would be two golfers working as team and the best score between them is counted per hole, the at the end we add those up.

Can this be done using a spreadsheet?

Comment: Excel and Google sheets are not the same and formula solutions will differ. Please specify which software you actually use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired result, the formula comes up quite complicated:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(MMULT((B12=$B$1:$E$1)*$B$2:$E$8,ROW(A1:A4)^0)>MMULT((C12=$B$1:$E$1)*$B$2:$E$8,ROW(A1:A4)^0),(B12=$B$1:$E$1)*$B$2:$E$8,(C12=$B$1:$E$1)*$B$2:$E$8))
```

but works in both Excel and GS

[image]

Comment: I had another look a this formula, and although its complicated it does exactly what i wanted it to do. A very big thank you. 

Answer (score 1):

In Excel you can use the LARGE() function. It is the easiest option but a bit verbose.

If you want to the sum of the top 3 values in a column/row:

```
 = large(A1:A10, 1), large(A1:A10, 2) + large(A1:A10, 3)
```

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(large(A1:A10,{1,2,3})` a little shorter

Comment: Thanks.

Sorry I hadn't explained it very well, maybe you read the outdated comment.

I can find the largest going down a col, but how do i find the largest of two cells (on the same row but different cols), and then add it to the next largest etc. until the end.

eg.
Another example would be two golfers working as team and the best score between them is counted per hole, the at the end we add those best scores.

Comment: Add a new column that's the max/min depending on what's a 'high score' and then sum that column for the total. But you want that full calculation in a single cell?

Answer (score 1):

In Excel

If one has the new dynamic array formula LET():

```
=LET(x,INDEX($B$2:$E$8,0,MATCH(I2,$B$1:$E$1,0)),y,INDEX($B$2:$E$8,0,MATCH(J2,$B$1:$E$1,0)),SUMPRODUCT(((x>y)*x)+((y>=x)*(y))))
```

[image]

Else

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((INDEX($B$2:$E$8,0,MATCH(I2,$B$1:$E$1,0))>INDEX($B$2:$E$8,0,MATCH(J2,$B$1:$E$1,0)))*INDEX($B$2:$E$8,0,MATCH(I2,$B$1:$E$1,0)))+((INDEX($B$2:$E$8,0,MATCH(J2,$B$1:$E$1,0))>=INDEX($B$2:$E$8,0,MATCH(I2,$B$1:$E$1,0)))*(INDEX($B$2:$E$8,0,MATCH(J2,$B$1:$E$1,0)))))
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Very nice dynamic versions for Excel! Seems with things like TEXTJOIN, LET, and XLOOKUP, Microsoft is finally getting around to common limitations we've had to roll our own solutions to forever.

Answer (score 0):

Either of the following formulas will produce the desired sums of 16 and 18 (tested on my machine):

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF($B$2:$B$8>$D$2:$D$8,$B$2:$B$8,$D$2:$D$8)))
=SUMPRODUCT(IF($B$2:$B$8>$D$2:$D$8,$B$2:$B$8,$D$2:$D$8))
```

Adjust to B->C and D->E for Bob + Tony. These formulas work by operating on arrays. They evaluate the `IF` statement once per cell in the `B2:B8` range and generate an array of values (`{3,4,1,3,2,2,1}`). Then `SUM` or `SUMPRODUCT` will sum those values. `ArrayFormula` is necessary to force `SUM` to deal with the IF as an array.

Further customization can be built from here as desired. Play around with `ArrayFormula` and `SUMPRODUCT` as they have much more powerful use cases than this and have parallels in other spreadsheet softwares including Excel.